# Unable to determine application identity of the caller - works on other machines

Tags: c#, debugging, isolatedstorage

When attempting to debug an application the code line

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile scope isolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
```

is returning the exception

```
System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException:
'Unable to determine application identity of the caller.'
```

The issue is that all other developers in our team **can** debug the code successfully. This would mean that there is nothing wrong with the code, but that the issue is on my machine.

Comment: Try opening your project properties, and on the Security tab enable ClickOnce security settings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IsolatedStorageFile exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284622/isolatedstoragefile-exception)

Comment: Laslos: The setting is enabled
Jeroen: I've confirmed that this is not the issue.

Comment: The exception is thrown precisely when `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ActivationContext` is `null`, which is normally the case if the code isn't being run in a ClickOnce context. You could try studying what's in this property for the working cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have it working (though I don't know what was happening).

The exception was occurring when trying to debug the application in VS2017. It runs successfully when debugging the application in VS2015.